# How to get secret environment variables implemented by kubernetes into python?

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, environment-variables, kubernetes-secrets

For my project I need a config file to connect my program to a database. Instead of writing the config data(for example username and password) hard coded in a document I want to save it as secure environment variables in kubernetes.

I programmed my application with python. The python application runs successfully in a docker container. I then created the secret variables via kubernetes. I wrote a .yaml file and specified the required container and image data.
That's the Kubernetes tutorial: [Link to Kubernetes tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-container-environment-variables-using-secret-data)

Now I want to access the secret environment variables I created in kubernetes. But how?

How can I read a secret environment variable with python? Do I have to initialize the environment variables in the docker file?

PS: I already tried things like this:

```
import os
print(os.environ['USERNAME'])
```

Comment: `os.environ` is correct. If the variable is not present, the problem is likely with your k8s configurations. Include the relevant k8s manifests in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Th following works and should prove this to you:

#### 1. Base64 encode e.g. username|password:

```sh
U=$(echo -n "freddie" | base64)
P=$(echo -n "fridays" | base64)
```

**NB** The host's environment variables are `U` and `P`

Assuming

```sh
POD="p"             # Or...
SECRET="s"          # Or...
NAMESPACE="default" # Or...
```

#### 2. Create the secret:

```sh
echo "
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: ${SECRET}
data:
  u: ${U}
  p: ${P}
" | kubectl apply --filename=- --namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

**NB** The Secret's data contains values `u` and `p` (corresponding to `U` and `P`)

yields:

```
secret/x created
```

And:

```sh
kubectl describe secret/${SECRET} --namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

yields:

```
Name:         ${SECRET}
Namespace:    ${NAMESPACE}
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  
Type:         Opaque

Data
====
p:  7 bytes
u:  7 bytes
```

#### 3. Attach the secret's values to a Pod:

```sh
echo "
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ${POD}
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: python
    command:
    - python3
    - -c
    - \"import os;print(os.environ['USERNAME']);print(os.environ['PASSWORD'])\"
    env:
    - name: USERNAME
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: ${SECRET}
          key: u
    - name: PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: ${SECRET}
          key: p
" | kubectl apply --filename=- --namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

**NB** The Pod's environment maps the Secret's `u`-->`USERNAME`, `p`-->`PASSWORD`

**NB** These variable name changes are to demonstrate the point; they may be the same

#### 4. Review the Pod's logs

```sh
kubectl logs pod/${POD} --namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

yields (in my case):

```
freddie
fridays
```